# Localise ASP.NET 2.0 App

Tags: asp.net, localization, webforms

At the moment, all of our localised texts are stored in resource files and then referenced using <% $Resouces:Something %>. Unfortunatly this method is not scaling too well, were getting lots of diff problems & the files are becoming rather big. Does anyone know of a better solution for localisation? Or is resource file's all I've got in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom resource provider to store localization data in a something other than a resx file. Here's a good article by Rick Strahl where he demonstrates how to store resource information in a database.

[Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization
Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/#To_Resx_or_not_to_Resx)

Here's an MSDN article on creating your own custom resource providers, it also includes a section on how to use a custom resource provider to access content from a database.

[Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx)

Comment: That's pretty sweet.  I wish I would have known about that a year ago.