# Displaying all the resources strings in a resx file

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, resources, internationalization

I have a "GUI Strings" .resx file in my application that holds all the strings that I display. I can obviously access each string directly via
    `Resources.Resource_GUI_Strings.CameraSettings_BrightnessLabel`

But how do I list all the settings in the .resx file, as their (name, value) pair, is my only option using reflection?

I want to list all the pairs (i.e. CameraSettings_BrightnessLabel & "Brightness") so that the user can edit the string for each item. This is so they can localise the GUI. I don't want to fully internationalise the app, the requirements are only for the user to be able to do it themselves.

So I need to be able to read the pairs of values from the .resx file and then write them back if the users edits them.

Just to add I want to do this at runtime inside the application itself, so I can't parse the .resx file on disk.

Comment: Why not use reflection? This doesn't sound like a piece of code that will run 1000 times in a loop. It sounds like it'll be on some kind of Edit->Options menu, so even with Reflection, you really won't notice any kind of performance hit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements.  Do you want to persist the values between application runs? Does each user customize their own version of the GUI, or should the customizations be shared by all users?

Comment: The customer is happy with basic internationalisation, so the only things they want it the ability for each user to change any label in the GUI from the default "English" label to their own. So the values need to persist but are only for that user of the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I'd use the [ResXResourceReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) and [ResXResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.aspx) classes, but my guess is that your resx files will be locked at runtime.  You may be better off storing the text in a database instead of resource files to get around this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528218/localise-asp-net-2-0-app/528320#528320) shows how to make a custom resource provider / resource manager to store/edit resources in the database.  Alternatively you could forgo the resource model altogether and roll your own solution.